# I have a segmentation fault and cannot seem to find it

Tags: c++

When I run this I get a segmentation fault but I'm not sure where it is. This is in c++. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance

```
    template<typename T>
    void My_vec<T>::insert_at_rank(int r, const T& elem){
        int init_size = size;
        if(r < 0){
            cerr << "Out of range"<<endl;
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (r <= size) {
           ++size;
        }
        else
           size = r+1;
        if (size > capacity) {
           T* new_ptr = new T[capacity*2];
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
              new_ptr[i] = ptr[i];
            }
        capacity = 2 * capacity;
        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = new_ptr;
        free(new_ptr);
        }

        for(int i = size-1; i > r; i--){
            ptr[i] = ptr[i-1];
        }
        for (int i = init_size; i < r; i++) {
            ptr[i] = '0';
        }
        ptr[r] = elem;  
    }
```

Comment: Without a [mcve], you will not get an answer. The real code that was triggering a segfault was obviously butchered rather badly, here.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. That should help you pin down which line of code the problem is happening at.

Comment: Debuggers are your friend.  You should at least know which line is segfaulting even if you can't explain why it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
    T* new_ptr = new T[capacity*2];  // allocates new array
    //...
    delete[] ptr;   // deletes previous array that 'ptr' pointed to
    ptr = new_ptr;  // repoints 'ptr' to the newly allocated array
    free(new_ptr);  // ???
```

Problem #1: `new_ptr` was allocated with `new []`. To deallocate it, you must use `delete []` *not* `free`.

Problem #2: `ptr = new_ptr;` sets `ptr` to point to the same `T[]` array as `new_ptr`. After `new-ptr` is deallocated `ptr` is left pointing to unallocated space. Yet, subsequent code attempts to dereference it in `ptr[i]`. That's UB ([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), and having the program segfault upfront is actually the luckiest of all scenarios